# ASP.net textbox Validation issue

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-4.0

i have a regular expression on ASP.net textbox control that validate for user input it should be only letters and numbers within  6 to 200 character 
this is my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory_description" runat="server" Style="width: 485px;" Height="70px"
                                                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Category name"
                                                            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{6,200}$" ControlToValidate="txtCategory_description"
                                                            Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

the problem is where i wrote in the textbox any HTML code like  it accept it and send me to error page of 
can any one help me ??

note : on my page i have another regular expressions if i left all of them wrong , that regular expression also work well , the problem appear if it is only the wrong one

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{6,15}$` describes a 6 to 15 character field, not a 6 to 200 character field as in your text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^([\-a-zA-Z0-9\._]){6,200}$`

Just as @user1428799 said, you need the 200, not 15.

That should do it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the hyphen needs to be placed in front (immediately after the **[** otherwise it's treated as a range character.

**Edit**
You can also just escape it as you may have to do so with the dot as well.

Comment: the problem not on the number of character used , but on that in not validate for HTML script injection
when i wire <html> as input for textbox that is the result of it :
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddSubCategories$txtCategory_description="<html>").